# MAUI Navigation is Returning Null

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, maui

So I have a code that I am supposed to convert to MAUI from XAMARIN. The question is that I written a code that kinda makes its own page with information. All of the functions on the information part is working fine. The problem is that when its supposed to open up the page that its filled with the information, basically the page does not open.
In the XAMARIN version we created a NavigationManager to navigate through pages. Whenever its coming to the navigation method, its says it is null. This is not the first time I have encountered this problem. When I first get this problem, I downloaded the NavigatableElement NuGet Package that comes with Microsoft.Maui.Controls. And this is how I fixed it at first:

```
private async void DataPacketsButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                //This is the old version that I used the NavigationManager That I have Created.
                //var manageDataPacketsPage = new ManageDataPacketsPage();
                //await NavigationManager.Instance.Navigation.PushAsync(manageDataPacketsPage, true);               
                //This is the method that I used the NuGet Package NavigatableElement.
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ManageDataPacketsPage());
        }
```

This is the one that I am trying to convert into the NavigatableElement:

```
        public async Task OpenParcelPage(string plotId)
        {
                var page = new ParcelPage();
                page.Fill(plotId);

                //This does not see the NavigatableElement Package. So its returning the "Navigation" Object null.
                await NavigationManager.Instance.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
```

This is the NavigationManager I created:

```
public class NavigationManager
    {
        public INavigation Navigation { get; private set; }

        #region Singleton
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();
        private static readonly object _updateLock = new object();
        private static NavigationManager instance = null;

        public static NavigationManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {
                            instance = new NavigationManager();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add to question the code that sets Navigation property. Also, while not the cause of the problem, you could simply set instance in a “static constructor”. Then, no lock needed. Or set it inline in the field declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the navigation manager was returning null was because i did not implemented that in the main page.

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //This is the one.
            NavigationManager.Instance.SetNavigation(Navigation);
        }
```

I know that not a lot of people is making their own navigation manager. What I`m supposed to do actually read and make how Alexander told me in the above. But if anyone stumble upon this problem they can fix it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with the capability of `INaviagtion`, you can write your own view service to navigate through pages.

Here's the code snippet for your reference on **navigating** from the first page to second page:

1. Create a view service: **ViewServices.cs**

```
public static class ViewServices 
{
       private static IServiceCollection Services;

       public static MauiAppBuilder UseViewServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
       {
            Services = builder.Services;
            return builder;
       }

        public static ContentPage ResolvePage<TService>(params object[] inputParameters)
        {
            var implementationType = Services
                                    .Where(service => service.ServiceType == typeof(TService) && service.ImplementationType != null)
                                    .Select(service => service.ImplementationType)
                                    .First();

           return (Activator.CreateInstance(implementationType, inputParameters)) as ContentPage;
        }
}
```

2. Create two interfaces respectively:

```
public interface IFirstPage 
{
}
```

```
public interface ISecondPage 
{
}
```

3. In first page code behind, note that the second page also needs to implement `ISecondPage`

```
public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage,IFirstPage 
{
      public FirstPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new FirstPageViewModel(this.Navigation);
      }
}
```

**FirstPage.xaml:**

```
<VerticalStackLayout> 
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <Button
            Text="Take me to 2nd Page"
            Command="{Binding NavigateToSecondPageCommand}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

4. **FirstPageViewMode.cs**

```
public partial class FirstPageViewModel 
{
    private INavigation _navigationService;

    public FirstPageViewModel(INavigation navigation) 
    { 
            this._navigationService= navigation; 
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async void NavigateToSecondPage()
    {
         await _navigationService.PushAsync(ViewServices.ResolvePage<ISecondPage>());
     }
}
```

5.In **App.xaml.cs**, change the starting page like below:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(ViewServices.ResolvePage<IFirstPage>());
```

6. **MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp() 
{
       var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
       builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  })
                  //don't forget adding the view service
                 .UseViewServices();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFirstPage, FirstPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ISecondPage, SecondPage>();
        return builder.Build();
}
```